# Query exist-db from Java

Tags: java, exist-db

i want to query existdb from Java. i know there are samples but where can i get the necessary packages to run the examples?

in the samples :

```
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import org.exist.storage.serializers.EXistOutputKeys;
import org.exist.xmldb.EXistResource;
import org.xmldb.api.DatabaseManager;
import org.xmldb.api.base.Collection;
import org.xmldb.api.base.Database;
import org.xmldb.api.modules.XMLResource;
```

where can i get these ?
and what is the right standard connection string for exist-db? port number etc

and YES, i have tried to read the existdb documentation, but those are not really understandable for beginners. they are confusing.
All i want to do is write a Java class in eclipse that can connect to a exist-db and query an xml document.

Comment: This exist db, doesn't it have any documentation? How about reading up here: http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/ ?

Comment: I have deleted my last comment.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is badly written, and I think you are really not explaining what you are trying to do very well.

If you want the JAR files as dependencies directly for some project then you can download eXist and get them from there. Already covered several times here, which JAR files you need as dependencies is documented on the eXist website and links to that documentation have already been posted in this thread.

I wanted to add, that if you did want a series of simple Java examples that use Maven to resolve the dependencies (which takes away the hard work), then when we wrote the [eXist book](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920026525.do) we provided just that in the **Integration Chapter**. It shows you how to use each of eXist's different APIs from Java for storing/querying/updating etc. You can find the code from that book chapter here: https://github.com/eXist-book/book-code/tree/master/chapters/integration. Included are the Maven project files to resolve all the dependencies and build and run the examples.
If the code is not enough for you, you might also want to consider purchasing the book and reading the Integration Chapter carefully, that should answer all of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

i ended up with a maven project and imported some missing jars (like ws.commons etc) by manually installing them on maven. 
the missing jars i copied from the existdb installation path on my local system.
then i got it to work.

Comment: That's also how I've done it here too.
For anyone else interested: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlrpc/xmlrpc-client
and
https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io
are availble on maven,
"exist.jar" and "xmldb.jar" are available from eXist-db (when you download, or build form source).
Those were the only libs needed to query a DB from tomcat/java (for me, so far...)

Answer (score 0):

from: http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/devguide_xmldb.xml

> There are several XML:DB examples provided in eXist's samples
>   directory . To start an example, use the start.jar jar file and pass
>   the name of the example class as the first parameter, for instance:
>
> java -jar start.jar  org.exist.examples.xmldb.Retrieve [- other
>   options]

```
Example: Retrieving a Document with XML:DB
import org.xmldb.api.base.*;
import org.xmldb.api.modules.*;
import org.xmldb.api.*;
import javax.xml.transform.OutputKeys;
import org.exist.xmldb.EXistResource;

public class RetrieveExample {

    private static String URI = "xmldb:exist://localhost:8080/exist/xmlrpc";

    /**
     * args[0] Should be the name of the collection to access
     * args[1] Should be the name of the resource to read from the collection
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

        final String driver = "org.exist.xmldb.DatabaseImpl";

        // initialize database driver
        Class cl = Class.forName(driver);
        Database database = (Database) cl.newInstance();
        database.setProperty("create-database", "true");
        DatabaseManager.registerDatabase(database);

        Collection col = null;
        XMLResource res = null;
        try {    
            // get the collection
            col = DatabaseManager.getCollection(URI + args[0]);
            col.setProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "no");
            res = (XMLResource)col.getResource(args[1]);

            if(res == null) {
                System.out.println("document not found!");
            } else {
                System.out.println(res.getContent());
            }
        } finally {
            //dont forget to clean up!

            if(res != null) {
                try { ((EXistResource)res).freeResources(); } catch(XMLDBException xe) {xe.printStackTrace();}
            }

            if(col != null) {
                try { col.close(); } catch(XMLDBException xe) {xe.printStackTrace();}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have seen these examples, but where to get the packages? how set up and test these samples?

Comment: Sandra - you can either 
1) use maven 
2) download database - http://sourceforge.net/projects/exist/files/Stable/2.2/

Then you should be able to start-up a database and connect to it mimicking the program above.

Comment: i do not work with a maven project. just want to create one simple java class.

Comment: what would be the dependency to add for eXistdb?

Comment: The dependencies are documented on http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/deployment.xml#D2.2.6

Answer (score 0):

On the page http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/deployment.xml#D2.2.6 a list of dependencies is included; unfortunately there is no link to this page on  http://exist-db.org/exist/apps/doc/devguide_xmldb.xml (should be added);

The latest xmldb.jar documentation can be found on http://xmldb.exist-db.org/

All the jar files can be retrieved by installing eXist-db from the installer jar; the files are all in `EXIST_HOME/lib/core`

Answer (score -1):

If you work with a maven project, try adding this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>xmldb</groupId>
    <artifactId>xmldb-api</artifactId>
    <version>20021118</version>
</dependency>
```

Be aware that the [release date](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/xmldb/xmldb-api) is 2002.

Otherwise you can query exist-db via XML-RPC

Comment: what would be the dependency to add for eXistdb?

Comment: this dependency is rather too old, please don't use it

Comment: @DiZzZz : As I added in my comment, its release date is 2002 to point out it is old.